# Creating an archive page or simple template to list all values of a custom field of specific post type listing

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type named 'lawyer' and it contains various custom fields. two of the custom fields are 'state' and 'city'. i want to create a archive page or simple page(anyone will do) which can list all the values of city for specific state. for example i have 10 listings. 5 of which have custom field 'state' value as "albama" now i want list of the values 'city' of all those five listings which has state as "albama" but i also want that reduntant city doesnt not showup. i.e. if 3 of cities are "florence" then they only showup once.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do, if I were you, would be to change the data structure so that the location would a hierarchical custom taxonomy where states were parent terms and cities their child terms.

Then you could create a custom taxonomy template for your location taxonomy. In this template you'd display list of child terms when the queried object is a parent term.

---

**EDIT 3.9.2019**

Here is a very basic example how to get the child terms in `archive-{post_type}.php` template

```
// WP_Term object
$current_term = get_queried_object();
// maybe array of WP_Term objects
$children = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
  'parent'   => $current_term->term_id
) );
// If any child terms exists
if ( $children && ! is_wp_error( $children ) ) : ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ( $children as $child_term ) : ?>
      <li><?php echo esc_html( $child_term->name ); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif;
```

A good place to learn more about custom post types is the Plugin Handbook, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/working-with-custom-post-types/

And if you're not very familiar with PHP yet, have a look at the PHP documentation Getting Started guide, https://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php, or use your preferred search engine to find tutorials and beginner level courses.

Comment: hey thanks for reply but can you send code forr template as i dont have much experience with php

Comment: @ChinmayRamraika, I added a simple example to my answer, which you can use as a starting point for learning. And if you need help with customizing your site, please consider hiring a professional developer.